# AppSync, pass array as an input argument with graphql-tag

Tags: arrays, react-native, graphql, aws-appsync, mutation

I'm using appSync with react-native, I have a mutation defined in my schema like this:

[Mutation Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMbEj.png)

And it works fine when I test the mutation in the query section

[Test mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YUHc.png)

The problem is that I'm not sure how to represent that with graphql-tag, I cannot figure it out how to pass the argument.

This is the representation I got:

[graphql-tag representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP2GD.png)

This is how I call the mutation:

[Call Mutaiton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EjKf.png)

And this is the query definition, where vitals is and array

[Query definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJAxE.png)

But the mutation does not execute, it rolls back. I only can see this:

[Mutation execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYpsE.png)

Anyone can help me out??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a variable `$vitals` but are not providing that key in `variables`.  You are setting variables with `variables: initValues.vitals` where `initValues.vitals` is the array of inputs that you want. You need to change it to `variables: initValues` so `vitals` remains a top level key that GraphQL can then find and replace the `$vitals` variable with.

Let me know if this fixes your issue.